# Writing out revised text erases file

Tags: vbscript

I've come up with a vbscript to find and replace a string on one line in a text file. I've echoed the new line to make sure that it is correct, but when I try to write the revised file out, all I get back is just the new line--the rest of my text file is erased.

Here is an example of the text file:

```
 LINE 1
 LINE 2
 LINE 3
 LINE 4
 UWI .     040291234500      SOME ADDITIONAL TEXT
 LINE 6
 LINE 7
```

My script is set up to find the line beginning UWI, check to see if the number beginning 040 is 14 digits and, if it isn't, append two zeros at the end of it.

Here's the script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "^UWI"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("I:\TX-HOU\GeoScience\User\U1\Hgordon\GGX_RECONVERSION\LAS\AG\LOGS\ARROYO_GRANDE\TEST\Adams 2.LAS", ForReading)
Set wrtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("I:\TX-HOU\GeoScience\User\U1\Hgordon\GGX_RECONVERSION\LAS\AG\LOGS\ARROYO_GRANDE\TEST\test1.txt", ForWriting)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
     strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
     Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  
     If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
         For Each strMatch in colMatches   
             uwi = Mid(strSearchString, Instr(strSearchString, "040"), 14)
             If Right(uwi, 2) = "  " then
                 newuwi = Left(uwi, 12) + Replace(Right(uwi, 2), "  ", "00")
                 newLine = Left(strSearchString, Instr(strSearchString, "040")) + newuwi + Right(strSearchString, InstrRev(strSearchString, "0")) + vbCrLf
                 'Wscript.Echo newLine
             End If
         Next

         wrtFile.Write newLine
     End If
 Loop

 objFile.Close
 wrtFile.Close
```

No matter where I put the wrtFile.Write newLine, I end up with a text file that only has that line and not the rest of the lines that were in the original file.

I'm hoping whatever I'm doing wrong is obvious to someone else, because I've searched everywhere and can't find an answer that will work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. My script above is set up to work against one file for now. Ultimately, I'll set it up so that it will go through an entire folder.

Comment: In what part of your code do you expect "*the rest of the lines that were in the original file*" to be written to the new file?

Comment: Considering that I don't know very much about coding, I've put together my code from various Google searches. One of the main ones I used for structure was this one from Tech Net: (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/08/how-can-i-find-and-replace-text-in-a-text-file.aspx) and this one from someone's blog: (https://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/vbscript-edit-line-in-file/). If there is more that needs to be added, that's what I need to know but can't find anywhere.

Comment: In that case, respectfully, *learn*. Coding is not like frying an egg. You can't "just do it", and there's no point asking very very basic questions if you don't understand how programming works. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code snippet might help (explained in comments):

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine

    ' assign default `newLine` value to (unchanged) input line
    newLine = strSearchString

    '
    ' conditionally modify `newLine` here (not tested)
    '

    ' write `newLine` (changed or unchanged) and newline character to the output file
    wrtFile.WriteLine newLine
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you, JosefZ. I appreciate your guidance. It helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.